# Human computer interaction - waiting in line

Tags: human-computer-interface

As part of my assignment, I am supposed to find out what would users like to do while they're waiting in line (for anything).

I would appreciate if you guys could provide your input.

Comment: While waiting in line, you could try reading the faq.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you give users something to do while your process is working, you risk massively alienating all of them. In my experience, users **hate** waiting entertainment especially if it creates the feeling that it might extend the actual waiting.

The very best thing to do in this situation IMO is to tell the users exactly how much longer they will have to wait so they can fill the time productively on their own.

Answer (score 0):

1. They may get their cellphones or smartphones to play games, browse
   on mobile internet, watch mobile TV, do SMS or call their friends.
2. There are others with newspapers and books and read these while they are in line.
3. Others might be daydreaming.
4. There are people busy listening to music.
5. If they have companions, they are going to chat with them.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your assignment in what? What does this have to do with programming? Do you intend to program the people in line? If so, I recommend the Clockwork Orange approach, complete with the 9th.